# What do the parenthesis mean in the set builder notation $\{(x,S)\mid x\in S, S\in 2^A\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, notation

I've looked around but can't quite figure out what the set produced by the builder notation in the title would actually look like - specifically, what element does $(x,S)$ actually yield? If someone could explain what the output of the statement would look like I would really appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: These are ordered pairs. The usual set-theory definition is $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}.$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair?wprov=sfti1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses in $(x,S)$ tell you that the elements of the set you are building are ordered pairs. In your example $A$ is some set, and $2^A$ is the set of all its subsets.

Pick a simple example, say $A = \{1,2\}$ and write out all the elements of the set you are building to see what is going on.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - odd for my lecturer to set a question like this without ever actually letting us know what a tuple is. With $A=\{1,2\}$ then it should be $\{(1,\{1\}),(2,\{2\}),(1,\{1,2\}),(2,\{1,2\})\}$ I believe.

Comment: You're welcome. You're right. Perhaps your instructor assumed (incorrectly) that everyone knew about ordered pairs. The way to thank folks here is to upvote useful answers and accept one that helps you the most.